# Updating fromTable ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I made a change password page using asp. When a user log in, he/she has an option to change a password by inserting a. old password in a text box, b.Inserting new password, c. Reinsert the new password. I created codes in the button OK for insert and I also made a selection using SQL string.Format. Every time I run the application, it works but no Updates been commence into my table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is not a typo then you have your variables the wrong way round.

```
string sql = String.Format("Update Registration set 
         Password ='{0}'where Username='{1}'", username, newpassword);
```